# "Thread is terminated" runtime error when initiating download

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, download, terminate

**The situation:**

In a C# web site project I am getting data out of a database and write the required data to an excel file server side, which I then want to offer for downloading.

**The problem:**

At the end of the code to initiate a download (See below) I get a runtime error that the thread is terminated and no file is offered for downloading.

**My code**

```
FileStream fStream = new FileStream(resultFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[(int)fStream.Length];
fStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
fStream.Close();

response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
response.AddHeader("Content-Length", byteBuffer.Length.ToString());
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(resultFile));
response.TransmitFile(resultFile);
response.End();
```

I hope somebody can help me with this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @GregoryNozik, is `TransmitFile` the right choice here? Looks like the OP wants a synchronous solution.

Comment: I should say interrupted rather than terminated by the way. Anyway, I tried it without the response.End and I didn't get the error, but neither did I get a dialog box to save the file offered for download. Instead of TransmitFile I also tried WriteFile(resultFile) and BinaryWrite(byteBuffer) but I got the same error...

Comment: Can the fact that the code is inside a web method have to do with it?

Comment: @Gregory Nozik: Well yes but it just stops executing the webmehod at the response.End line and fiddler shows a 500, or without that line I get a 200 but nothing happens

Comment: What browsers have you tries this on? (IE is more sensitive, it requires the page URL to match the name of the downloaded file, for example)

Comment: I did the same functionality using HTTP handler and it's working fine

Comment: The problem turned out to be that the code was inside a web method. Once I put the code in the page load of a different ASPX.CS file, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following code to download Excel

```
   FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path);
   byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];
   fs.Read(data, 0, (int)fs.Length);
   Response.Buffer = true;
   Response.ContentType = "application/x-msdownload";
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName  );
   Response.BinaryWrite(data);
```